# Why is Windows 7 ejecting my CD-ROM?

Tags: windows-7, eject, compact-disc

I'm inserting a CD-ROM with some older software on it into the DVD drive. When the drive settles down, Windows Explorer shows the drive as E: under Computer. As soon as I click on the E: icon, the disk ejects and I get a message "Please insert a disk into drive E:". If I push it back in, Windows just pushes it back out again.

Why is it doing that?

Comment: This can happen with a blank disk.  Does explorer show data on the disk?  Do you have another computer handy to test the disk with?

Comment: Post your latest edit as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I downloaded the latest Windows updates and restarted the PC - the problem went away.

I don't know if it was the update or just restarting that fixed it. There were only 5 updates, none of them critical.